# Check if id exists in MongoDB with pymongo and scrapy

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I have set up a spider with scrapy that sends data to a MongoDB database. I want to check to see if the id exists so that if it does I can $addToSet on a specific key (otherwise Mongo will reject the insert because the _id already exists).

This is my pipelines.py:

```
import pymongo

class MongoDBPipeline(object):

    collection_name = 'logfile'

    def __init__(self, mongo_uri, mongo_db):
        self.mongo_uri = mongo_uri
        self.mongo_db = mongo_db

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(
            mongo_uri=crawler.settings.get('MONGO_URI'),
            mongo_db=crawler.settings.get('MONGO_DATABASE', 'items')
        )

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.client = pymongo.MongoClient(self.mongo_uri)
        self.db = self.client[self.mongo_db]

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.client.close()

    def idExists(self, item, spider):
        #this next line is where I'm running into trouble
        if self.db[self.collection_name].find({'_id': dict(item['_id'])}).limit(1).size() > 0
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if idExists == False:
            self.db[self.collection_name].insert(dict(item))
            return item
        else:
            pass #write the line to add only to the array with $addtoset
```

My items.py looks like:

```
import scrapy

class CallLog(scrapy.Item):
    _id = scrapy.Field()
    placed = scrapy.Field()
    answered = scrapy.Field()
```

and my spider looks like:

```
import scrapy
import time

from callStats.items import CallLog
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from selenium import webdriver


class LogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "logspider"
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.domain.com/log1.htm",
        "http://www.domain.com/log2.htm",
        "http://www.domain.com/log3.htm"
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        scrapy.Spider.__init__(self)
        self.browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()

    def __del__(self):
        self.browser.exit()

    def parse(self, response):
        item = CallLog()
        self.browser.get(response.url)
        time.sleep(3) #Wait for javscript to load in Selenium

        if response.request.url == "http://www.domain.com/log1.htm":
            idname = "Kirk"
        elif response.request.url == "http://www.domain.com/log2.htm":
            idname = "Jim"
        elif response.request.url == "http://www.domain.com/log3.htm":
            idname = "Spock"

        # scrape dynamically generated HTML
        hxs = Selector(text=self.browser.page_source)
        item['_id'] = idname
        item['placed'] = hxs.xpath('myxpath1').extract()
        item['answered'] = hxs.xpath('myxpath2').extract()
        return item
```

I'm getting a syntax error in my pipelines.py on this line:

```
if self.db[self.collection_name].find({'_id':dict(item['_id'])}).limit(1).size() > 0
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 150, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\commands\crawl.py", line 57, in run
    self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 153, in crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1274, in unwindGenerator
    return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1128, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 71, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 83, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 67, in __init__
    self.scraper = Scraper(crawler)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\scraper.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.itemproc = itemproc_cls.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 56, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 32, in from_settings
    mwcls = load_object(clspath)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 44, in load_object
    mod = import_module(module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
exceptions.SyntaxError: invalid syntax (pipelines.py, line 36)
2015-11-11 11:12:27 [twisted] CRITICAL:
```

I'm pulling my hair out because I feel like I'm really close to getting this working. In robomongo, when I run this query:

`db.getCollection('logfile').find({'_id': 'Jim'})`

It shows me Jim's document. I just can't for the life of me figure out what to put inside the find() so that it grabs the _id of the current page that I'm crawling.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: can you add the Traceback? what is "item"?

Comment: As far as I can tell, "item" is the data that scrapy scrapes. the line in def process_item : `self.db[self.collection_name].insert(dict(item))` works fine when there are no documents in the collection. So I thought that if I referenced the ['_id'] it would work, but apparently not.

Comment: I think it should be `if self.db[self.collection_name].count({'_id':dict(item)['_id']})> 0 `

Comment: I tried your code, but I'm still getting the same syntax error.

Comment: what is the output of `print(dict(item))`?

Comment: it prints out the data that was scraped in the form {"key": "value"}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94846/discussion-between-eitan-and-user3100115).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to create a new method in the pipeline, I instead checked for the existence of the '_id' key inside the process_item method like so:

```
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if self.db[self.collection_name].find({'_id': dict(item)['_id']}).limit(1).count() > 0:
            pass
        else:
            self.db[self.collection_name].insert(dict(item))
```

Hat tip to [user3100115](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3100115/user3100115) for help with the syntax.

Comment: why are you using `limit` and `size`? You query will always return 0 or 1 document because `_id` are unique. Also You should use the `find_one` method instead but frankly I will go for `count()`

Comment: I ended up removing `size()` and replaced with `count()`. I read [here](https://blog.serverdensity.com/checking-if-a-document-exists-mongodb-slow-findone-vs-find/) that the performance of `find_one` wasn't that great. I modified the code above.

Comment: you can remove `limit(1)` also